# On POST, Pass Object IDs rather than full object

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was wondering if there was a way in Spring Boot to pass the IDs of an object in an Array which Spring Boot will then get the object details for rather than the full object

This is an issue for me as to find the object, it appears Spring Boot wants the full object which will not work in my case

For example

```
{
    "request": [
                   "e77d8168-4217-43c9-a6dd-fb54957d1302"
               ]
}
```

Rather than having to pass

```
{
    "request": [
                   {
                       "uuid": "e77d8168-4217-43c9-a6dd-fb54957d1302",
                       "name": "Object 1"
                   }
               ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, sure you can. Why couldn't you? It's just JSON, and you're dree to pass whatever you want. Just make sure to create a class that matches with the JSON structure in order to be able to map it to an object automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The problem is probably with the class you are using to map your `List<String>`. It must match your json. Your controller should be like:

```
@RestController
public class IdsController {

    @PostMapping("endpoint")
    public void postIds(@RequestBody IdRequest idRequest){
        idRequest.getRequest().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

And the request object:

```
public class IdRequest {
    private List<String> request;

    public List<String> getRequest() {
        return request;
    }
}
```